# Modal Popup Extender: Fetch data from database then bind it to the label in the modalpopupextender

Tags: asp.net, modalpopupextender

I've a problem with ModalPopupExtender. I have put a label in ModalPopupExtender and trying to bind label with the value from database. When I am debugging, the value is showing on the label's text (ie there is no database error), but it is not displaying when the popup window is shown.

Can any one help me please ????????

Here's my code

### Code on html

```
<asp:Panel ID="PopupPnl" runat="server">
  <table style="width:100%;"> 
    <tr>
      <td >
         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" 
                    Text="View Description" >
         </asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td >
         <asp:Label ID="label_Descrption" runat="server" >
         </asp:Label>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="background-color:White;">
      <td >
         <asp:Button ID="btnExit" runat="server" Text="Exit"/>
      </td>
   </tr>  
  </table> 
 </asp:Panel>
<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" 
            style="display:none;"/>
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" 
                        TargetControlID="btnShowPopup" 
                        PopupControlID="PopupPnl" 
                        CancelControlID="btnExit" 
                        BackgroundCssClass="ModalPopupBG" >

</cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
```

### Code on c#

```
 protected void lbn_Template_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    util_Category objUtilCategory = new util_Category();
    cl_Category objClCategory = new cl_Category();
    if (ddlSubCategory.SelectedItem.Text != "--Select A SubCategory--")
    {
        objClCategory.CategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlSubCategory.SelectedValue);
        Label lbl = (Label)PopupPnl.FindControl("label_Descrption");

        label_Descrption.Text = objUtilCategory.GetATemplate(objClCategory);
        ModalPopupExtender2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you binding the label? Is the Binding Container (DetailView, GridView, Repeater) of the label Inside or outside the popup? Is the data binded before or after showing the popup? How are you shouwing the popup (server/client side)? **Please provide some code.**

Comment: I've posted the code as per your suggestion.Please go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `Panel` which contains the `label_Description` inside `UpdatePanel`.

Comment: Hi Mr.Waqas,its work fine and thanks a lot.If you don't mind can you tell me why panel is placed inside update panel.

Comment: Actually UpdatePanel provides you a functionality to refresh part of your pages, so what ever is placed inside the UpdatePanel can be updated without updating or postbacking the entire page.. For more details you could refer to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx ...